# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 with string of date field

Tags: php

I have got this issue:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in every row of `$news_date[1]`.

Here are my code:

```
$news_date=explode("-",$press_date);
    if($news_date[1]==1){
    $news_date[1]='JAN';
    }else if($news_date[1]==2){
    $news_date[1]='FEB';
    } //and so on..
$press_date=$news_date[1].', '.$news_date[0];
```

I stored date data with `news_date` field.

Please kindly suggestion How can I should do.

Thank you very much in advance.

*** Editable****
After ask via Stack now I have used these code to solve my problem.
It is just using 3 lines. Thank you Adrian Preuss for your suggestion.

```
    $press_date=$rs['news_date']; // store data from DB
    $new_formatDate=date("M d, Y",strtotime($press_date));  // Set Date Month Year styles that I want
    $new_formatDate = strtoupper($new_formatDate);  // Make it to ALL CAP
```

Comment: *"Thank you very much in advance."* - what does that mean?

Comment: Please provide sample data from `$press_date` and **validate** the Array-Entry with `isset($news_date[1])` for sample!

Comment: @AdrianPreuss this is an sample data: 2014-07-21

Comment: it means there is no data in $news_date[1]. this can be due to $press_date is empty or $press_date has one string without '-' like $press_date('10') without any '-'. check $press_date

Comment: Did you know PHP has various functions specifically for handling dates?

Comment: `DateTime()` class would be useful here

Comment: @Don'tPanic True, but simplicity is sometimes efficient as well :) Besides, its a learning curve.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you! I did it already. Sorry if my question make the Stack like spam! But I don't know how I start to research. Anyway, I know now and my proble is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wan't to work with `Date formats`- Your problem is, you **split** the Date simply with `explode` - This way is not correct, because your splitted data has following format:

```
[0] "2014"
[1] "07"
[2] "21"
```

You check the splitted **string** (after splitting, each entry is also an **string** to) with integers:

```
if("07" == 1) {
```

The second problem is, you don't validate, if the data is set. The next problem is: You want to display only another date **format** - Please use PHP-based functions for formatting. Here are a sample for you:

```
<?php
$press_date = '2014-07-21';

print date('d. M Y', strtotime($press_date));
```

> **Output:** 21. Jul 2014

```
<?php
$press_date = '2014-07-21';

print date('l, d. F Y', strtotime($press_date));
```

> **Output:** Monday, 21. July 2014

Informations about the **output format** can be found at http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php.

Comment: Many thanks Adrian! This is my fault. Now I am using DateTime() to show the data. ANyway, Your suggestion is help me too much. So sorry to cannot click your comment to "USEFUL".